# What happened to General Grievous's fighter?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, a-new-hope, revenge-of-the-sith, general-grievous

In Episode III, Obi-Wan Kenobi steals the personal starfighter of General Grievous and escapes with it, picking up Luke and Leia along the way.

What happened to this spaceship? Did he sell it on Tatooine (e.g. to get enough money to buy his house)? Did he still have it by the time of Episode IV? If so, why couldn't he and Luke have traveled to Alderaan in it rather than needing to charter a flight with Han? Was it inoperative after all of those years? Was it simply too small to fit both of them plus the droids? Do we ever find out the final fate of the fighter?

Any level of canon information is welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Main canon

The last that's heard of the fighter is that it was used to transport Obi-Wan from Utapau to the Sundered Heart.

> But Obi-Wan Kenobi killed the Separatist general before he could get
> away. After Obi-Wan was betrayed by his clone troops, he flew
> Grievous’s fighter to a rendezvous with Bail Organa and Yoda.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Databack - The Soulless One](https://www.starwars.com/databank/soulless-one)</sup></sub>

---

### Legends.

The ship receives a further mention in [Star Wars: The Life and Legend of Obi-Wan Kenobi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Life_and_Legend_of_Obi-Wan_Kenobi). Obi-Wan disposed of it at a spaceport en route to Tatooine. It's not entirely clear whether he sold it or simply abandoned it.

> *R2-D2 had been to the Lars family moisture farm just prior to the
> Battle of Geonosis, and was able to provide the farm’s coordinates to
> Obi-Wan. The starfighter that Obi-Wan had taken from the late General
> Grievous had remained in Tantive IV’s docking bay, and **Obi-Wan planned
> to use the starfighter to take Luke to a spaceport at Nar Shaddaa, a
> moon in a space sector controlled by the Hutts. As Obi-Wan carried
> Luke into the starfighter’s cockpit, R2-D2 beeped a farewell message
> to the Jedi.** There was no point in Obi-Wan saying goodbye to C-3PO,
> for Bail Organa had already taken the security precaution of having
> the talkative protocol droid’s memory erased.   **Holding Luke
> Skywalker’s swaddled form against his chest, Obi-Wan Kenobi sat in an
> uncomfortable seat on a crowded, Tatooine-bound starcruiser.** The Jedi
> Master had little experience holding babies, but he did his best to
> look comfortable with the child in his arms.*
>
> *Bail Organa had provided a supply of untraceable credits for Obi-Wan
> to pay for the journey to the sand planet. To further maintain
> secrecy, Obi-Wan and Luke were traveling to Tatooine via an indirect
> route starting from Nar Shaddaa on a series of public transports.
> During a layover at a space station, Obi-Wan witnessed a group of
> travelers at a HoloNet kiosk, watching a broadcast about recent events
> on Coruscant. Obi-Wan had cringed when he saw a hologram of Emperor
> Palpatine urging viewers to report anyone whom they suspected of being
> a Jedi or having “supernatural powers.” Palpatine’s words had prompted
> one traveler to remark, “Thank goodness those terrible Jedi were
> stopped!”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Life and Legend of Obi-Wan Kenobi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Life_and_Legend_of_Obi-Wan_Kenobi)</sup></sub>

It makes a further appearance in the *Star Wars Galaxies* expansion pack "Rage of the Wookiees". Evidently it was recovered by [N-K Necrosis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/N-K_Necrosis) from a secret Empire storeroom on Utapau and used by this character until his death. At that point [the deed transfers to the player character](https://youtu.be/j7ZngdFPLBM?t=7m12s).